# The XML specification is not valid:

Tags: azure

The XML specification is not valid: The element 'WebRole' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceDefinition' has incomplete content. List of possible elements expected: 'Sites' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceDefinition'.

Here is the XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ServiceDefinition name="AzureCloudService1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceDefinition" schemaVersion="2015-04.2.6">
  <WebRole name="Web" vmsize="Small">

    <Startup>
      <Task commandLine="StartUp.cmd" executionContext="elevated" taskType="background" />
    </Startup>

  </WebRole>
</ServiceDefinition>
```

Comment: Can you share the XML?

Comment: Please check gaurav.

Comment: There's something wrong with your csdef file. Please see the schema for csdef file here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/gg557553.aspx. How did you create this file?

Answer (score 0):

As the error says.... Your `<WebRole>` tag  must include a `<Sites>` node.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a  Azure Cloud Service project, there will be a default `ServiceDefinition.csdef` in Solution Explorer with the content below,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ServiceDefinition name="AzureCloudService1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceDefinition" schemaVersion="2015-04.2.6">
  <WebRole name="WebRole1" vmsize="Small">
    <Sites>
      <Site name="Web">
        <Bindings>
          <Binding name="Endpoint1" endpointName="Endpoint1" />
        </Bindings>
      </Site>
    </Sites>
    <ConfigurationSettings>
      <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString" />
      <Setting name="StorageConnectionString" />
    </ConfigurationSettings>
    <Endpoints>
      <InputEndpoint name="Endpoint1" protocol="http" port="80" />
    </Endpoints>
  </WebRole>
  <WorkerRole name="WorkerRole1" vmsize="Small">
    <ConfigurationSettings>
      <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString" />
    </ConfigurationSettings>
  </WorkerRole>
</ServiceDefinition>
```

So, you are missing a `<Sites>` node.